# Undefined method while running tests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I want to write tests for my program and when I run
bin/rails test test/models/inventory_test.rb

I get error

```
# Running:

E

Error:
InventoryTest#test_quantity_should_not_be_negative:
NoMethodError: undefined method `variations' for #<#<Class:0x000000010862c9e8>:0x000000010864a290>
    test/fixtures/inventories.yml:2:in `get_binding'
```

Now I created fixtures based on my models and my inventories.yml looks like this:

```
one:
  variation_id: <%= variations(:one) %>
  warehouse_id: <%= warehouses(:one) %>
  quantity: 50
  updated_by_user_id: <%= users(:one) %>
  product_id: <%= products(:one) %>
  created_at: <%= fake_time %>
  updated_at: <%= fake_time %>

two:
  variation_id: <%= variations(:two) %>
  warehouse_id: <%= warehouses(:two) %>
  quantity: 100
  updated_by_user_id: <%= users(:two) %>
  product_id: <%= products(:two) %>
  created_at: <%= fake_time %>
  updated_at: <%= fake_time %>
```

Now I don't know why it tries to get variations method, I don't have one and I don't know how to debug this one. Tried everything.

My Inventory model looks like this :

```
class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :warehouse
  belongs_to :variation
  belongs_to :updated_by, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "updated_by_user_id"

  has_many :inventory_transactions

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  has_one :restock_alert, dependent: :destroy
  after_save :check_restock_alert

  def check_restock_alert
    if self.quantity <= self.restock_alert.threshold
      self.restock_alert.update(status: RestockAlert::TRIGGERED)
    elsif self.quantity > self.restock_alert.threshold
      self.restock_alert.update(status: RestockAlert::PENDING)
    end
  end
  
end
```

Tried in other fixtures to make variation_id: one and so on, leads to other issues.
This one feels like closest I can be to solution but it checks for variations method which I don't have.

Comment: it tries to get the variations method because that's what you typed in the fixtures file, on line 2!

Comment: I'd suggest using either fixtures *or* factories, not both. Fixtures are a lot more rigid and harder to control, so in my experience they're really not worth the trouble. Factories can do everything fixtures can do and way more.

Comment: @tadman thanks! Factiories seems to be working well!

Comment: @LesNightingill Thanks but I still don't understand why it calls variations. for Class.. :(

Comment: I don't use fixtures, so I'm not sure. But `variations(:one)` has the syntax of a ruby method. Perhaps it should be a hash? `variations[:one]`?

Comment: `variations(:one)` refers to the fixture file `variations.yml`. It will look in that file for a variation named `one:`.  Fixtures allow you to skip having to reference the associations by *_id. So in your inventories.yml you can replace that line with `variation: one` and it will look for a variation record with that name.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using .erb syntax in your inventories.yml file since it is not needed. In fixtures you can create records that reference each other via associations without having to do that much work. So given your file of:

```
one:
  variation_id: <%= variations(:one) %>
  warehouse_id: <%= warehouses(:one) %>
  quantity: 50
  updated_by_user_id: <%= users(:one) %>
  product_id: <%= products(:one) %>
  created_at: <%= fake_time %>
  updated_at: <%= fake_time %>
```

if you have a variations.yml like this:

```
one:
   foo: bar
   ...
```

You only need to do this in your inventories.yml

```
one:
  variation: one
  warehouse: one #assumes a warehouses.yml with a record with that name
  quantity: 50
  updated_by_user: one
  product: one
  created_at: <%= fake_time %>
  updated_at: <%= fake_time %>
```

Comment: The `updated_by_user` should work, but it's a renamed association so I can't say I'm 100% sure.